# Format number of seconds as mm:ss in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am displaying a number of seconds that counts down from 3600 to 0.

```
<div class="time-box" *ngIf="p.value.playerTimer > 0">{{ p.value.playerTimer }}</div>
```

I would like to format the number of seconds as **minutes:seconds**

I hoped to be able to use DatePipe - https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

```
<div class="time-box" *ngIf="p.value.playerTimer > 0">{{ p.value.playerTimer | date:'mmss' }}</div>
```

But this doesn't work as it expects `p.value.playerTimer` to be a date object or number of seconds since the epoch.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: that is right... it will expect the date's int value or a valid date. you have to write your own directive for this feature

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Angular Date Pipe works with number value too,
**But please note: Only with milliseconds**.

If you want to get `mm:ss(00:00)` you need to convert your number value to milliseconds. In your case it should be: `3600 * 1000`

```html
<div class="time-box" *ngIf="p.value.playerTimer > 0">
    {{ p.value.playerTimer * 1000 | date:'mm:ss' }}
</div>
```

here is the Stackblitz example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-pipe-example-nhafvx

maybe someone will come in handy

Comment: This should be the chosen answer, this is exactly why the date pipe did not work for the asker.

Comment: This doesn't take into account local time zones. For example during BST a duration of 0 milliseconds will be displayed as 1 hour. It will appear to work fine during the winter though .

Comment: hmm, can you try to add `date:'mm:ss':'UTC'`?

Comment: I can confirm that adding the `'UTC'` part does the trick to avoid the extra added hours in some timezones.

Only downside to using date pipe is that any overflow is ignored, so if the OP's input is more than 59:59, it will just show 00:00.

Comment: Hi @mneumann I just tested, it works with `UTC`, I have tried for `3655` and it shows `01:00:55`

Answer (score 35):

You have to write your own pipe. Something like this. Be aware though, it's untested and does not take into account any strange input it might receive. Also it does not have any leading zeros, but hey, now you got something to do as well:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'minuteSeconds'
})
export class MinuteSecondsPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: number): string {
       const minutes: number = Math.floor(value / 60);
       return minutes + ':' + (value - minutes * 60);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the idea

Comment: Modify the return statement to padding the zeros, ex ```2:4``` will be ```02:04```
```return minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + (value - minutes * 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');```

Answer (score 20):

To put all the answers together plus a sample usage in HTML:

From markau and PierreDuc:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'minuteSeconds'
})
export class MinuteSecondsPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: number): string {
       const minutes: number = Math.floor(value / 60);
       return minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + 
           (value - minutes * 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    }
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<div ...>{{ p.value.playerTimer | minuteSeconds }}</div>
```

So for example, if p.value.playerTimer = 127, it will show 02:07

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking for an answer that goes a step further and supports hours:

```js
const toHoursMinutesSeconds = totalSeconds => {
  const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
  const minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 3600) / 60);
  const seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
  let result = `${minutes
    .toString()
    .padStart(1, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
  if (!!hours) {
    result = `${hours.toString()}:${minutes
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
  }
  return result;
};
```

Produces:

```js
toHoursMinutesSeconds(55);
'0:55'
toHoursMinutesSeconds(679);
'11:19'
toHoursMinutesSeconds(12345);
'3:25:45'
toHoursMinutesSeconds(123456);
'34:17:36'
```

Answer (score 3):

Following from [PierreDuc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46055604/3003102), if you want to pad the minutes/seconds with a leading zero (e.g. 00:01), you can use the ES2017 `padStart` method:

`return minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + (value - minutes * 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');`

Answer (score 1):

> case 1 int = 100 output 01:40
>   case 2 int = 50 output 00:50
>   case 3 int = 125 output = 02:05

```
transform(value: number, args?: any): string {

    const hours: number = Math.floor(value / 60);
    const minutes: number = (value - hours * 60);

    if (hours < 10 && minutes < 10) {
        return '0' + hours + ' : 0' + (value - hours * 60);
    }
    if (hours > 10 && minutes > 10) {
        return '0' + hours + ' : ' + (value - hours * 60);
    }
    if (hours > 10 && minutes < 10) {
        return hours + ' : 0' + (value - hours * 60);
    }
    if (minutes > 10) {
        return '0' + hours + ' : ' + (value - hours * 60);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [francisco-danconia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558928/3337028), I was getting the **mm:ss** as ==> **04:58.69999999999999**. So I modified the code slightly as follows. I am now getting 04:58 as expected.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'minuteSeconds'
  })
  export class MinuteSecondsPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(value: number): string {
         const minutes: number = Math.floor(value / 60);
         return minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + 
         Math.floor((value - minutes * 60)).toString().padStart(2, '0');
      }
  }
```