# Mask hours and minutes

Tags: angular, typescript

I used the Datediff function to get the difference between dates in minutes.

My problem is that I cannot display the result in the following hh: mm format.

Right now it's like 0: 3, the value I get is 3 minutes, I intend to 00:03.

**COMPONENT**

```
 var sec_num = self.Minutes  //self minutes = 3 minutes;
        var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor(sec_num - hours * 60);
        self.display = hours + ":" + minutes ;
        return self.display;
```

**HTML**

```
<span>{{display}}</span>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ziaiw2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Do you have moment js library?

Comment: @SiddharthPal yes

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539028/converting-seconds-into-hhmmss) can help. Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055278/format-number-of-seconds-as-mmss-in-angular-2) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321653/angular-datepipe-convert-seconds-to-time-with-zero-timezone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Angular's `DatePipe`: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nebuv9

```
{{display | date: 'hh:mm' }}
<br>
{{display | date: 'hh:mm:ss' }}
<br>
{{display | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss' }}
```

**2nd solution based on your comments:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bx6tg5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

`self.display = hours + ":" + ('0' + minutes).slice(-2);`

Try it with other values than 3 minutes.

Comment: The datepipe doesn't work the way I get the minutes ... I only get a 3 and the format is 0: 3 :(

Comment: If display is a Date then it'll work: `display: Date = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0);` then `{{display | date: 'mm:ss' }}`. I updated the Stackblitz.

Comment: I tested but it didn't work :( I updated the post and put the Stackblitz link to see the code and test. Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: This case works well in the example, the problem is that I will not always receive the value of 3 minutes, I can receive 2 hours and 15 minutes for example and then it will no longer work

Comment: If you don´t want to convert "display" to a Date object you can just format the string as you want. I added another Stackblitz base on your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment js to format as below

```js
console.log(moment({"minutes": 3}).format('HH:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there another solution without daring moment.js? I updated the post and put the Stackblitz link to see the code and test. Thanks for trying to help me